# Selecting a row from a dataframe based on condition in R

Tags: mysql, r, dataframe

I am trying to subset a dataframe based on each `user_id` and `order_date`.

If `ecomm_id` and `pulse_id` exists in the row for that `userid` and for `order_date`, that row should be selected to new dataframe.

Else only one row with no `ecomm_id` must be selected to the new data frame and all other rows must be discarded.

Sample data:

```
userid  returning   device store_n  testid      ecomm_id pulse_id order_date
 1.00      1          0     9328    Experience E    1       23     7/25/2015
 1.00      1          0     NA      Experience E    NA      NA     7/25/2015
 2.00      1          1     NA      Experience C    NA      NA     7/14/2015
 3.00      1          0    3486     Experience F    2       86     7/23/2015
 3.00      1          0     NA      Experience F    NA      NA     7/24/2015
 3.00      1          0     NA      Experience F    NA      NA     7/24/2015
```

Expected Output:

```
userid  returning   device store_n  testid      ecomm_id pulse_id order_date
 1.00      1          0     9328    Experience E    1       23     7/25/2015
 2.00      1          1     NA      Experience C    NA      NA     7/14/2015
 3.00      1          0    3486     Experience F    2       86     7/23/2015
 3.00      1          0     NA      Experience F    NA      NA     7/24/2015
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps!

```
df <- data.frame(userid=c(1,1,2,3,3,3),
                 returning=c(1,1,1,1,1,1),
                 device=c(0,0,1,0,0,0),
                 store_n=c(9328,NA,NA,3486,NA,NA),
                 testid=c('Experience E','Experience E','Experience C','Experience F','Experience F','Experience F'),
                 ecomm_id=c(1,NA,NA,2,NA,NA),
                 pulse_id=c(23,NA,NA,86,NA,NA),
                 order_date=c('7/25/2015','7/25/2015','7/14/2015','7/23/2015','7/24/2015','7/24/2015')
                 )

library(dplyr)
df1 <- unique(df) %>% group_by(userid,order_date) %>% summarise(count=n())
df1 <- merge(unique(df),df1,on=c(userid,order_date))

final_df <- df1[!(is.na(df1$ecomm_id) & is.na(df1$pulse_id) & df1$count > 1),-ncol(df1)]
```

*Don't forget to let us know if it solved your problem :)*

Answer (score 1):

With `data.table`, this becomes a concise "one-liner":

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)[order(ecomm_id), .SD[1], keyby = .(userid, order_date)]
```

> ```
>    userid order_date returning device store_n     testid tid ecomm_id pulse_id
> 1:   1.00  7/25/2015         1      0    9328 Experience   E        1       23
> 2:   2.00  7/14/2015         1      1      NA Experience   C       NA       NA
> 3:   3.00  7/23/2015         1      0    3486 Experience   F        2       86
> 4:   3.00  7/24/2015         1      0      NA Experience   F       NA       NA
> ```

By ordering by `ecomm_id`, the `NA` entries are moved to the bottom. Now, for each combination of `userid` and `order_date` the first element within that group is picked.

Note that this assumes that there is *at most one entry* per group in case of non-NA `ecomm_id`s because the OP has specified:

> If `ecomm_id` and `pulse_id` exists in the row for that `userid` and for `order_date`, that row should be selected to new dataframe.